# XTR115 current loop transmitter more steady output

Tags: arduino, current-source

I'm using a XTR115U in my circuit to make a 4-20mA output. As I found out this IC is a current amplifier based on the below image on the datasheet.

[image]

To test this IC, I connected the 2.5V Vref using a 20K resistor to pin2 (Iin). But I have a flicker on the output with a magnititude of 0.01 mA, and on the other hand the circuit is very dependent to tempreture as I heated the 20K resistor the output changed dramaticly.

What is the best practice to make use of this IC?

Comment: Follow the data sheet and app note

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check all your connections. Look at the output with an oscilloscope as well as a meter.

Connect a 10nF capacitor across the loop connections at the transmitter end.

Make sure your Vloop is a minimum of 7.5V + ~22mA * RL (RL is inclusive of your current meter input resistance).

Do **not** add a capacitor on Vref without implementing one of the compensation schemes described in the datasheet.

Comment: Yeah Thank you it was the meter I changed it to a better one it is not because of the circuit It was the meter.

Comment: Do you know how much current I can get from the 5V regulator?

Comment: A few mA, both from the typical curves and the necessity to keep Iq well  under 4mA under all conditions.